# Problem sending file over http connection using flutter

Tags: android, http, flutter, dart, server

I'm having a problem with sending an image file as an Http response from a flutter http server. When the code DOES seemingly work, the image is downloaded to the client under the right name, but is corrupted and unable to be opened. And a lot of the time, the client throws an exception: `Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.` This has been tested with multiple images and on physical devices.

Using this code in tandem on two android devices on a LAN network, the target IP is hard coded for one of the devices. (advice on how to get that ip from a broadcast or something would be appreciated :)

server:

```
Future _startWebServer() async {
  runZoned(() {
    String requestString;
    HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 8080).then((server) {
      server.transform(HttpBodyHandler()).listen((HttpRequestBody body) async {
        requestString = utf8.decode(body.body);
        switch (requestString) {
          case 'fileName':
            {
              body.request.response.write(basename(_imageFile.path));
              body.request.response.close();
              break;
            }
          case 'file':
            {
              body.request.response.write(_imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
              body.request.response.close();
              break;
            }
          default:
            {
              body.request.response.write('hello from server!');
              body.request.response.close();
            }
        }
      });
    });
  },
    onError: (e, stackTrace) => print('Oh No! $e $stackTrace'));
}
```

client:

```
File _imageFile;
void _receiveData() async {
  String fileName = "FILE1";
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.11:8080"))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      request.headers.contentLength = utf8.encode('fileName').length;
      request.write('fileName');
     return request.close();
  })
  .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents){
      centerText = contents;
      fileName = contents;
    });
    setState(() {});
  });
  Directory tempDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  var fileSave = new File(tempDir.path + '/' + fileName);
  var _downloadedData = List<int>();
  await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.11:8080"))
      .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
    request.headers.contentLength = utf8.encode('file').length;
    request.write('file');
    return request.close();
  })
      .then((HttpClientResponse response) async {
    print('Received file');
    //------------------Decode error here-----------------
    response.listen((d) => _downloadedData.addAll(d),
    onDone:(){
      fileSave.writeAsBytes(_downloadedData);
    });

    setState(() {
    _imageFile = fileSave;
    });
  });
  client.close();
}
```

Any advice, critiques, and comments on the problem or the code in general would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try opening the images in HEX editor and look for the differences in comparison to original ones. Maybe you are writing some other data to it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realize `body.request.response.write()` converted the `_imageFile.readAsBytesSync() as List<int>` to a string. Fixed by changing `body.request.response.write(_imageFile.readAsBytesSync());` to `body.request.response.add(_imageFile.readAsBytesSync());`

.add "adds" a `List<int>` to the response body.